# Pandas: Count Unique combinations from multiple columns and write amount in new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Lets say i have following dataframe df:

```
col1    col2 
-------------
apple   apple
melon   apple
apple   apple
pear    melon
```

Now, how do i count all combinations and write it into a new column? Like this.

```
col1    col2   amount
---------------------
apple   apple    2
melon   apple    1
pear    melon    1
```

Comment: Use `df.groupby(['col1', 'col2']).size().reset_index(name='amount')`

Comment: Does it also work with NaN entries or empty string? Because the count doesnt sum up with the total row number.

Comment: NaNs values are excluded, emoty string working nice.